# .htaccess não aceita arquivo para erro 403

Tags: php, htaccess

Fiz assim no meu **.htaccess**

```
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
```

Mas dá o **erro 403** em vez de exibir a **página** do erro!

Se eu fizer:

```
ErrorDocument 403 403.php
```

Isto é, em o / antes do 403. Aparece o texto **403.php** na página como havia de se esperar.

Isso me leva a acreditar que oi **.htaccess** está sendo tratado.

Meu **403.php** está na raiz!

Como corrigir isso?

Comment: Você tentou usar `localhost/403.php` ?

Comment: sim, abre normalmente a página pois ela existe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
```

O `/403.php` pode não ser o caminho absoluto para a raiz da sua pasta `public_html`,`htdocs` ou `www` por exemplo, mas sim a raiz do seu sistema de arquivos. Este pode ser, com base na configuração, por exemplo, `/home/htdocs/` etc e assim por diante.

Então, o que você precisa fazer é descobrir o caminho absoluto e defini-lo de acordo.

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22976772/errordocument-404-404-php-is-not-working-in-htaccess-file-in-php

Comment: isso, era isso mesmo. Pois ainda não criei virtual hosts. Todos os sites ficam no localhost. Muito obrigado! Mas, tenho ainda uma dúvida: Se o htaccess está na raiz do site, então o / não deveria ser o mesmo diretório onde está o .htaccess?

Comment: se puder me ajudar nessa outra dúvida de .htaccess agradeceria muito! https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/402836/repassar-regra-access-a-subdiret%C3%B3rio-existente